# Print xml version from a shell script

Tags: xml, shell

I am trying to write xml version header to a file from a sh script using echo command. Until now, I tried with :

```
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' >> "$DEST_FOLDER/$REPORT_FILE"
```

but nothing is printed. Also, I escaped " character, but with no result. If the last " is missing, this line is written to file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8?>
```

I really can not understand where the problem might be. Could someone explain me what is happening? Thanks!

Comment: don't forget that `>>` will be appending to the end of the file. When you open your file to look at the results, you'll always be looking at your first attempt at the top of the file. Also its not completely clear in your question, but did you escape the last dbl-quote inside that echo statement? You need to.Good luck.

Comment: The problem is somewhere other than in that line. That line is perfectly fine assuming reasonable values for `$DEST_FOLDER` and `$REPORT_FILE`.

Answer (score 1):

The command you've written works fine when I use it in a sh script.

```
#!/bin/sh
DEST_FOLDER='.'
REPORT_FILE='test.xml'
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' >> "$DEST_FOLDER/$REPORT_FILE"
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

Also seems to work in bash, ksh and zsh...